# Exercise concerning complement of direct product from Mendelson's Topology

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

In Bert Mendelson's *Introduction to Topology*, the first exercise of Ch. 1 Sec. 5 states:

> Let $X\subset A$ and $Y\subset B$. Prove that $$C(X\times Y)=A\times C(Y)\cup C(X) \times B.$$

I have seen a "proof" of this, but I remain unsatisfied with the result. As support, I offer the following as a counterexample.

Let $A=\{-1,0,1\}=B$. Also let $X=\{0,1\}$ and $Y=\{-1,0\}$. These satisfy the preconditions. Now, is it true that

$$(\{0,1\}\times \{-1,0\})^C=\{-1,0,1\}\times \{-1,0\} \cup \{0,1\}^C\times \{-1,0,1\}.$$

It is easy enough to see that $X\times Y=\{(0,0),(0,-1),(1,0),(1,-1)\}$. The complement* would then be anything not in this set, for example $(2,2)$. However, certainly $(2,2)$ is in neither $\{-1,0,1\}\times \{-1,0\}$ nor $\{0,1\}^C\times \{-1,0,1\}$.

(*Is this definition of complement correct?)

Is there some underlying assumption of which I should be aware? Is staying within the bounds of the parent sets a standard practice? Is my counterexample unreasonable? Please advise.

Comment: C stands for complement, is it?The complement in  some universal set, in this case $\mathbb{R}$, maybe?

Comment: I thought that $C$ represented the cone operator, and was thinking that the question was completely nonsensical.

Comment: $XxY$ is not what you think it is. Think about that first, how can $XxY$ be a finite set if $X$ and $Y$ are both infinite? Look up the definition of cartesian product.

Comment: @M.Van The notation is suspect. I think $[-1,1]$ means $\{ -1,1\}$, and $[0,1]$  means $\{ 0,1\}$, for example.

Comment: Yes, $C(X)$ means complement of $X$ in the book to which I referred. I changed my notation to the more usual, $X^C$. Also, I originally used $\mathbb{R}$ for the intervals... now I have fixed that notation to show the change to integers.

Comment: To get an idea of what this formula says, sketch a picture with $A=B=\mathbb R$  and $X=Y=[0,1]$ and see what the RHS of the formula is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context it is understood that the complement of $Y$ is taken with respect to the containing set $A$, the complement of $X$ is taken with respect to the containing set $B$, and the complement of $X\times Y$ is taken with respect to the containing set $A\times B$. Thus, the complement of $X$ is $\{-1\}$, the complement of $Y$ is $\{1\}$, and the complement of $X\times Y$ is

$$\{\langle -1,-1\rangle,\langle -1,0\rangle,\langle -1,1\rangle,\langle 0,1\rangle,\langle 1,1\rangle\}\;,$$

which is indeed equal to

$$\big(\{-1,0,1\}\times\{1\}\big)\cup\big(\{-1\}\times\{-1,0,1\}\big)\;.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is this the usual way to take such a statement, or is it just because it's the first chapter of an introduction to topology?

Comment: @Matt: You’re welcome. It’s the usual way to understand such a statement. The problem with complements is that they make sense only when the appropriate containing set has been specified, and when it *isn’t* specified, it takes a bit of experience to recognize what is implied by context. This is why I prefer not to use ‘naked’ complements at all: I always use relative complements, so that I’d write $$(A\times B)\setminus(X\times Y)=\big(A\times(B\setminus Y)\big)\cup\big((A\setminus X)\times B\big)\;.$$

Comment: Very good. It makes sense, I just thought it would be specified. Thanks.

Comment: @Matt: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$$(p,q)\in (A\times B) \backslash (X\times Y)\iff$$ $$\iff (\;(p,q)\in A\times B \land (p\not \in X\lor q\not \in Y)\;)\iff$$ $$\iff (\;(p,q)\in A\times B \land p\not \in X\;)\lor (\;(p,q)\in A\times B \land q\not \in Y)\;)\iff $$ $$\iff (\;(p\in A \backslash X \land q\in B)\lor (q\in B \backslash Y \land p \in A)\;)\iff$$ $$\iff (\;(p,q)\in (A \backslash X)\times B)\lor (p,q)\in (A\times  B \backslash Y)\;)\iff$$ $$\iff (p,q)\in (\;(A \backslash X)\times B)\cup (A\times (B \backslash Y)\;).$$

Comment: very logical!!!